# Insert HTML element into DOM with React

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I'm using Regex to bold characters using a double underscore. This is my regex, which works:

```
"I'm making __this__ bold".replace(/\__([^*]+)\__/g,"<b>$1</b>");
```

Which gives me this:

```
"I'm making <b>this</b> bold"
```

But how do I get it work with React? I have the following code, which doesn't work:

```
 {cars.map(car => {
   return (
    <div>
     <p>{car.description.replace(/\__([^*]+)\__/g,"<b>$1</b>")}</p>
    </div>         
  )})}
```

In this case {car.description} would be for example:

```
   "The __Audi RS 6 quattro__, commonly referred to as __the RS6__"
```

And I would like it to show up as:

"The **Audi RS 6 quattro**, commonly referred to as **the RS6**"

### EDIT:

With this

```
  <p>{car.description.replace(/\__([^*]+)\__/g,"<b>$1</b>")}</p>
```

I get back a string:

```
   "The <b>Audi RS 6 quattro</b>, ..."
```

But how do I make JSX recognise to show it as bold, and not with the 
 tags on the frontend?

Comment: Please try this, `<p>{car.description.replace(/\__([^*]+)\__/g,"<b>$1</b>")}</p>`

Comment: [why and how](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [**dangerouslySetInnerHTML**](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html)

```
{cars.map(car => {
   var description = car.description.replace(/\__([^*]+)\__/g,"<b>$1</b>");
   return (
    <div>
     <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: description}}/>
    </div>         
  )})}
```

Sample snippet

```js
const App = () => {
   var car = "I'm making __this__ bold";
   var newCar = car.replace(/\__([^*]+)\__/g,"<b>$1</b>");
   return (
       <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: newCar}} />
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: What if `description` contains characters such as `&` or `<`?

Answer (score 0):

I advise against using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, which — as implied by its name — is dangerous (the output won’t be what you expect if `car.description` contains characters such as `&` or `<`).

You can produce your own elements instead:

```
return (
  <p>{car.description.split('__').map((v, i) => i % 2 ? <b key={i}>{v}</b> : v)}</p>
);
```